# Eclipse CDT Settings

Tags: eclipse, compilation, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to compile one single cpp file with Eclipse CDT and MinGW. On command line, c++ Test.cpp does the job. If I try to compile the file with Eclipse, I get errors telling me that I don't have included string.h in my lib files.

How do I setup Eclipse just to perform "g++ Test.cpp" without considering my lib files as independent files? Thanks for helping :)

Kon

Answer (score 1):

In the *Project Explorer* tab, *right click* one (or more) of your **.cpp** file(s) and select *Build Selected File(s)*.

Comment: And where is that context option , because I don't see it in latest Juno eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to exclude my lib files by right clicking on the folder "exclude from build ..." :) Thanks!